# Ajax: Send PHP variable to JS without echo?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm fairly new to both PHP and Ajax, so this might seem trivial, although I couldn't seem to find a clear answer to this.

I'm sending a query to a process.php using ajax, and then display the result on the page. What I've got works fine and everything's ok:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "process.php",
   data: { 'data1': yada, 'data2': yadayada},
   beforeSend: function(html) {
      $("#some-div").html('<p>loading</p>');
   },
   success: function(html){
      $("#some-div").html(html);
   }
});
```

Now, this works because I'm basically echoing the result of the query at the end of process.php, which then gets displayed in #some-div. The thing is, I'd also like to retrieve some of the data that was processed in the PHP to use it in my JS. However, I don't want to echo this data at the end of the PHP, as I don't want to display it in #some-div.

In other words, say my process.php looks like this:

```
$var1 = "hello world";
$var2 = "It's sunny outside";
$var3 = ["key1"=>"one", "key2"=>"two", "key3"=>"three"];

$result = $var1 . $var3["key2"];
echo $result;
```

The $result gets displayed in #some-div, that's fine. But what if I'd like to make a wonderful alert(); in JS with the content of the $var3["key3"] without displaying it in #some-div?

Should I make another query to do so (which seems inconvenient and inefficient), or is there a way to pass data from process.php to the JS without echoing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output the data as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) so that you can have separate parts or variables:

```
$response = array('result' => $result, 'otherData' => $var3);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "process.php",
   data: { 'data1': yada, 'data2': yadayada},
   dataType : 'json', // <-- tell jQuery to parse the JSON
   beforeSend: function(html) {
      $("#some-div").html('<p>loading</p>');
   },
   success: function(response){
      alert( response.otherData.key3 );
      $("#some-div").html(response.result);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

php:

```
echo json_encode(array(
  'html' => 'this outputs into the div',
  'other_data' => 12345,
));
```

js:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "process.php",
   data: { 'data1': yada, 'data2': yadayada},
   beforeSend: function(html) {
      $("#some-div").html('<p>loading</p>');
   },
   success: function(data){
      $("#some-div").html(data.html);
      alert(data.other_data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting an objet from the function on success. that objet contains the response from the php file,
only 2 things to add.
in the `data:` parametter its more convinient to use the `serialize()` method.
and two: i strongly recomend you to return a json objet from the php file. in that case you will be reciving a javascript objetc, very easy to use.

sorry about my english. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So, conclusion is, yes, you have to output some data, or result in your server side script, because when you open connection with xmlhttp.open() you are basically fetching result outputed to browser of executed script.